# Flexslider not loading properlly

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I never saw a similar problem. When I load the page the flexslider doesn't load, but when I open chrome's web inspector or firebug it loads.
On iPad the same thing, it doesn't load when the page is loaded and when I touch and hold down-up it loads..

I'm loading the css file, lib file and calling the flexslider function normally inside a `$(function(){...})`:

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    animationLoop: true,
    itemWidth: 215,
    minItems: 2
});
```

and also tried `$(window).load`

Has anyone else had this problem before?

Comment: Where in your document is the above JS?

Comment: im calling all js after the body is close.
`<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/javascript/plugins.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/javascript/cycle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/javascript/browser-selector.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/javascript/masked-input.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/javascript/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>`

Comment: I see the flexslider working here. What browswer are you having trouble with? An unrelated issue, `.jspane` has a border in Chrome when you click the scrollbar. Just add `.jspane:focus{border:0px}` to your CSS and you'll be fine.

Comment: not working at all.. also tested on OSX Lion Chrome 24.0.1312.56, Firefox 18.0.1.
win7: ie8, ie9, chrome 24.0.1312.56

Comment: by the way thanks about the border, i didnt noticed, but its the small of the problem ://

Comment: Can you replicate your problem in a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: On what page(s) is the slider not working?

Comment: ADVOGADOS on the menu nav in the left of the page

Comment: Works here (Chrome 24/WinXP). Takes a moment to init though. Can you add the init as a callback of the page transition?

Comment: Is your flexslider inside of a div that is initially hidden (the link 404's now).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **$(window).load** try **$(document).ready**

Comment: didnt work at all. here is the link of my problem http://www.estudiocaju.com.br/homolog/dicavalcanti/test/
you can click on nav menu ADVOGADOS and you'll see only 1 image on the middle of the page.. try to open firebug or web inspector and it'll work